# How to connect my Hyper-V VM to a USB tablet (or device in general)?

Tags: windows, usb, virtual-machine, hyper-v

This question might look like a duplicate but I checked and actually this should not be the case. Here I want to be able to connect a USB device (not a hard drive, but a tablet, a phone or an mp3 player) to my Hyper-V guest Windows OS. Other questions focuses on how to connect a USB hard drive.

**System info**
I am running Hyper-V Manager 6.2 on host Windows Server 2012. Guest OS is Windows Server 2012 R2.

### Connecting a tablet

Looks like there is no way in the `Settings...` section of a VM to attach USB devices. I have an Android tablet I need to connect to my Windows guest OS, but I cannot get it done.

I searched and looks like there are USB redirectors out there but no Microsoft solutions! Is it possible? Is there really no Microsoft authored solution for connecting USB devices to a VM?

Comment: Which version of Hyper-V are you using (what's the host OS)?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Cool. Do you have Enhanced Session Mode enabled?

Comment: Your use case sounds desktop virtualization-ish. I suggest you use VirtualBox or VMware Player (or maybe even Workstation). They are vastly superior to Hyper-V in this area.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: I do not really know, let me check...

Comment: @DanielB: I know as I use VMWare and it is so easy... unfortunately I cannot use any other VM but Hyper-V for what I need to do :(

Comment: [Virtual Machine Connection - Enhanced Session Mode Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dn282274.aspx)

Comment: I guess my Host is Windows Server 2012 (no R2)... looks like it is not supported...

Comment: I am trying to upgrade to 2012 R@...